# Python: Schedule a block/closure for execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that I want to asynchronously schedule for execution.
I've tried doing this:

```
time.sleep(3)
print("Do stuff")
```

But this is blocking my script and it's also just kind of stupid looking.

How do I rewrite this Javascript code in Python?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    print("Do stuff")
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

I came up with this:

```
import threading
thread = threading.Timer(3.0, do_stuff)
thread.start()
```

I don't want to use threads. Threads are stupid.

Comment: Why did I get a minus point for this? This is like a really valid question.

Comment: Javascript has an event loop built into the language core. Python doesn't. Things like `setTimeout` don't make much sense without threads or an event loop.

Comment: Ok, so how does Tornado work?

Comment: Tornado has an event loop. (I don't know what else it does - I don't use Tornado - but Googling `tornado event loop` shows it uses one.)

Answer (score 0):

If using Tornado, the answer is this:

`tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(timedelta(seconds=1), do_stuff`)

No need to use threads